# Eclipse editor that unpackages/repackages files on open/save?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'd like to create an Eclipse editor plugin that will show a decoded portion of a file rather than the raw original, and then re-encode the file upon saving.  For example, an editor for a docx file that would unzip the archive, display the various xml component files in different tabs, and upon saving, would write them all out and rezip the archive.  Can anyone point me to an existing project that does something like this?  So far the examples I've seen based on ISourceViewer and ITextViewer only read the file as it exists on disk.

Thanks!
--Andy

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `org.eclipse.pde.internal.ui.editor.plugin.ManifestEditor` from PDE. This editor does not unzip the input, but it does decode the different parts of the input files...